# Traceback Error and KeyError, Cant seem to get this working. any Ideas?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am trying to get the code below to work, by extracting information from a csv file to a sqlite database, when I try to execute, I keep getting this Key Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    to_db = [(i['iddd'], i['Country'], i['StateCode']) for i in dr]
KeyError: 'iddd'
```

My code:

```
import csv, sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('Movies.db')
cur = con.cursor()  
cur.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Info;')
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Info(iddd INT PRIMARY KEY, Country INT, StateCode TEXT);")

with open('practice1.csv', 'rU') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    to_db = [(i['iddd'], i['Country'], i['StateCode']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Info (iddd, Country, StateCode) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", to_db)
con.commit()`
```

Comment: does your csv file contain the header iddd?

Comment: Are you using `,` or `;` to sepparate cells in the CSV? If you use `;` without declaring it explicitly, that is probably triggering the error... It would be good if you edit the question providing this information

Comment: What does your csv file look like?

Comment: What you stated Worked! I typed the Wrong headers, I got confused and stated the headers in my DB instead of the headers of my csv file. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So, if you could resolve the problem, it would be good that you post an answer on your own question explaining how did you resolve it.